# Github API POST /authorizations returns 401

Tags: javascript, ajax, curl, github-api, electron

I want to do Basic Auth with the GitHub Api from an Electron application. I'm trying to send an Ajax request from the Electron application to the GitHub Authorizations API to create an access token. The request works when I do it through cURL but I can't translate it to the Ajax request.

It works when I use cURL:

```
curl -i -u <username>:<password> -d '{"scopes": ["gist"], "note": "Wilson"}' https://api.github.com/authorizations
```

However, when I send the Ajax request, I get back a `401 Unauthorized`. I have tried to make the request using Postman as well as outside of Electron and I get the same response. I can see that the credentials are set in the request.

**Code :**

```javascript
// AJAX 
$.ajax({
  url: "https://" + c.username + ":" + c.password + "@api.github.com/authorizations",
  type: "POST",
  data: { "scopes":["gist"], "note":"Wilson" },
  success: function() {
    console.log('Successful response', arguments);
  }, error: function(xhr) {
    console.log('error', xhr);
  }
});
```

**Request headers**

```
POST /authorizations HTTP/1.1
Host: api.github.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 29
Accept: */*
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 2D4D31D9-46FE-4707-8FD3-1C6EB08A37F7
Origin: file://
Authorization: Basic <username>:<password>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3)  AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) wilson/0.0.1 Chrome/47.0.2526.110  Electron/0.36.8 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US
```

**Copy request as cURL**

```shell
curl 'https://api.github.com/authorizations' 
-H 'Cookie: _octo=GH1.1.1866616140.1454567890; _ga=GA1.2.1909561787.1456625032; logged_in=yes; dotcom_user=applegrain' 
-H 'Origin: file://' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' 
-H 'Accept-Language: en-US' 
-H 'Authorization: Basic <username>:<password>' 
-H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' 
-H 'Accept: */*' -H 'X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 2D4D31D9-46FE-4707-8FD3-1C6EB08A37F7' 
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) wilson/0.0.1 Chrome/47.0.2526.110 Electron/0.36.8 Safari/537.36' 
-H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data 'scopes%5B%5D=gist&note=Wilson' --compressed
```

When I copy the request as cURL and try to run it I also get a `401 unauthorized`. What's the difference between the first cURL command and the subsequent Ajax request? Could this an Electron issue?

Thanks - let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Did you try POSTing JSON? `data: JSON.stringify({ "scopes":["gist"], "note":"Wilson" }),`

Comment: @Prinzhorn just tried it but I still get a 401 "/

Comment: I don't know how GitHub is configured, maybe it's choking on the `Origin` header and rejects the request because it is not configured for CORS? Try the curl without `-H 'Origin: file://'`. If that doesn't work try removing options one by one until you end up with your original curl (just data and credentials)